# Program crashes when reading from plist

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to read from a `plist` which reads as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
<dict>
    <key>question</key>
    <string>2 + 2 = ?</string>
    <key>A</key>
    <string>2</string>
    <key>B</key>
    <string>4</string>
    <key>C</key>
    <string>3</string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>question</key>
    <string>2 + 4 = ?</string>
    <key>A</key>
    <string>3</string>
    <key>B</key>
    <string>6</string>
    <key>C</key>
    <string>9</string>
</dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

I am trying to update the View Controller when a UIButton is pressed but there seems to be an error in reading from the array. Have a created the array wrong. The first questions is displayed fine but when the button is pressed it crashes. The breakpoint shows the line that crashes is

> self.questionasked.text = question[currentQuestion];

Here is the code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
rootArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"question" ofType:@"plist"]];

currentQuestion = -1;
[self showNextQuestion];
}
 -(void) showNextQuestion{
        currentQuestion++;
    int numItems = [rootArray count];
    NSMutableArray *question = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numItems];
    NSMutableArray *A = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numItems];
    NSMutableArray *B = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numItems];
    NSMutableArray *C = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numItems]; 

for (NSDictionary *itemData in rootArray) {
    [question addObject:[itemData objectForKey:@"question"]];
    [A addObject:[itemData objectForKey:@"A"]];
    [B addObject:[itemData objectForKey:@"B"]];
    [C addObject:[itemData objectForKey:@"C"]];

    self.questionasked.text = question[currentQuestion];
    self.answer1.text = A[currentQuestion];
    self.answer2.text = B[currentQuestion];
    self.answer3.text = C[currentQuestion];

    }
}

-(IBAction)nextQ:(UIButton *) sender{

[self showNextQuestion];

 }
```

Comment: Please post the symbolic stacktrace.

Comment: where is that? how do i get it

Comment: Run your app in the debugger, wait for it to crash and you should be able to use `bt` in the debugger window to get the backtrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try putting these line of code outside your `for` loop.

```
self.questionasked.text = question[currentQuestion];
self.answer1.text = A[currentQuestion];
self.answer2.text = B[currentQuestion];
self.answer3.text = C[currentQuestion];
```

Answer (score 0):

First get data from `plist` file, here `yourArray` is `NSArray`

```
yourArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"FileName" ofType:@"plist"]];    

for(int i=0; i < yourArray.count; i++)
{
  NSLog(@"%@",[array objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"question"]);
  NSLog(@"%@",[array objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"A"]);
  NSLog(@"%@",[array objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"B"]);
  NSLog(@"%@",[array objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"C"]);
}
```

OutPut display in Consol.

Answer (score 0):

When you use:

```
rootArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"question" ofType:@"plist"]];
```

You'll get an `autoreleased` `NSArray`, that's why it crashes, change that to:

```
rootArray = [[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"question" ofType:@"plist"]] retain];
```

If you are using ARC use like:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *rootArray;
```

and

```
self.rootArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"question" ofType:@"plist"]];
```

Comment: I am using ARC....when I ran the project it gave me the error use of undeclared identifier '_rootArray' did you mean 'rootArray'?

Comment: I have got the problem fixed without using this method, but I am curious as to what this means for my project?

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need to change the way you load the plist into the array because it will autoreleased change this :

```
rootArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"question" ofType:@"plist"]];
```

with  this :

```
 rootArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"question" ofType:@"plist"]];
```

and the you got another error that will cause a crash you must get this lines in the showNextQuestion method :

```
self.questionasked.text = question[currentQuestion];
    self.answer1.text = A[currentQuestion];
    self.answer2.text = B[currentQuestion];
    self.answer3.text = C[currentQuestion];
```

out of the for sentence the code should be like this:

```
-(void) showNextQuestion{
        currentQuestion++;
    int numItems = [rootArray count];
    NSMutableArray *question = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numItems];
    NSMutableArray *A = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numItems];
    NSMutableArray *B = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numItems];
    NSMutableArray *C = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numItems]; 

    for (NSDictionary *itemData in rootArray) {
        [question addObject:[itemData objectForKey:@"question"]];
        [A addObject:[itemData objectForKey:@"A"]];
        [B addObject:[itemData objectForKey:@"B"]];
        [C addObject:[itemData objectForKey:@"C"]];

        }
         self.questionasked.text = question[currentQuestion];
        self.answer1.text = A[currentQuestion];
        self.answer2.text = B[currentQuestion];
        self.answer3.text = C[currentQuestion];


    }
```

good luck..